# Performance issues using huge arrays in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem where distances between a huge amount of points need to be calculated. Since I'm not an expert in C++ I would like to get some ideas on how to improve this code. The following version is running and giving the correct output, tested for a small system. But, depending on the system sizes, the calculation takes nearly forever (e.g. size > 17000).

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <fstream>
#include  <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int X1 = 0;
    double Rcut = 0.440910452039;
    int size = 100000;

    double* A = new double[size];
    double* B = new double[size];
    double* C = new double[size];
    double* E = new double[size];
    double* F = new double[size];
    double* G = new double[size];
    double** H = new double*[size];
    double** K = new double*[size];
    double** L = new double*[size];
    double** D = new double*[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        H[i] = new double[size];
        K[i] = new double[size];
        L[i] = new double[size];
        D[i] = new double[size];
    }

    if (argc <= 1) {
        cout << "No file name entered. Exiting..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

  ifstream infile(argv[1]); //open the file


  while ( !infile.eof () ) {
    infile >> A [X1];
    infile >> B [X1];
    infile >> C [X1++];
    }

  X1--;

    for ( int i = 0; i < X1; i++ ){
        E[i] = A[i]*46.8213;
        F[i] = B[i]*40.5462;
        G[i] = C[i]*50.357;
    }

    ofstream outfile ("results.txt");
    if (outfile.is_open())
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
            for ( int j = 0; j < size; j++ ){
                H[i][j] = E[i]-E[j];
                K[i][j] = F[i]-F[j];
                L[i][j] = G[i]-G[j];
                D[i][j] = sqrt(H[i][j]*H[i][j]+K[i][j]*K[i][j]+L[i][j]*L[i][j]);

                if (D[i][j]<Rcut) {
                    outfile << i+1 << " " << j+1 << " " <<D[i][j] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        outfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Given the lack of description of what your program does and not-helpful variable names it's impossible to say how it might be refactored.

Comment: As a side note, you should seriously consider `delete`-ing your pointers.

Comment: You should avoid using `new`. It is unnecessarily hard to get correct. There also doesn't seem any reason to allocate your memory in so many small pieces.

Comment: You can't beat time complexity. You need to process every pair, that's `O(n^2)`. I doubt you can get very much with micro optimization, your code is already pretty simple. 50% would be nice, so you'd have `nearly foverer / 2`

Comment: You are very wasteful of memory, E[], F[] and G[] are all unnecessary - you could multiply A[], B[] and C[] in-place by your constants.

Comment: While i can only guess, it probably has something to do with the ridiculous usage of `new`.  Look up some information on stack and heap allocations in C++

Answer (score 5):

Your performance problem is basic math:

```
int size = 100000;

// ...

for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    H[i] = new double[size];
    K[i] = new double[size];
    L[i] = new double[size];
    D[i] = new double[size];
}
```

So, you run this loop 100000 times. Each time in the loop you allocate four 100000 element arrays. `sizeof(double)` is 8. Let's calculate how much RAM you need.

```
100000 * 100000 * 4 doubles
```

That's how many `double`s you are allocating. With each `double` taking up 8 bytes, the total amount of bytes required is

```
100000 * 100000 * 4 * 8 = 320000000000 bytes
```

Or about 300 gigabytes of RAM. It's somewhat unlikely that your machine has 300 gigabytes of RAM. Your host operating system probably uses a variable-sized swap file, so, before long, you're going to be thrashing all of this data to/from your hard drive, constantly.

That's your performance problem (I am not including the dozen misc 100000-element arrays you also allocate, which by this time are insignificant line noise).

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions have already been made in the comments, but the main performance issue is that your algorithm has a time complexity of O(n^2).

If I understand it correctly, you want to find all pairs with a distance smaller than `Rcut`. You could save a lot of time if you first sort your array of points with respect to one of the components. Then you will only have to compare each point with a small range of other points because if the difference in coordinate values is larger than `Rcut`, the distance also has to be larger.

I am assuming here that most of the point pairs hava a distance larger than `Rcut`. In this case you will only have a time complexity of approximately O(n log(n)), which is due to the sorting. Of course in the worst case, meaninc that all points are within a sphere of diameter `Rcut`, this won't save you anything.

Answer (score 1):

- As Mark states in the comment, do not store intermediate results in arrays if you do not need them later
- You are iterating over a 2D array with every combination of i and j in the full range. this leads to O(n^2) complexity. But, there is a condition `D < Rcut`, which basically means that the distance between i and j has to be below a limit for the iteration to be relevant. Rcut is already named to be interpreted as radius. For any i, you only have to iterate over a range of values for j, which are near i. If you get the math straight there, you essentially get O(n)
- a small thing you could do: do not calculate the sqrt, compare against (Rcut)^2 instead. (This will *not* really help you in any way, just mentioning for completeness)

Answer (score 0):

calculate:

```
`D[i][j] = 0;
D[i][j] += H[i][j]*H[i][j];
D[i][j] += K[i][j]*K[i][j];
D[i][j] += L[i][j]*L[i][j]);
D[i][j] = sqrt(D[i][j]);`
```

And so you can calculate H,K,L one by one.
But it seems that a double type matrix of size 100000*100000 is too large.
It require 74G memory above.
And so you can read file in piecewise,and calculate D[i][j] for i,j piecewise.
Here's the O(n log n) code by @Frank Puffer@philipp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct point3d
{
public:
    point3d(double x_,double y_,double z_):
        x(x_), y(y_), z(z_)
    {}
    point3d(const point3d& rhs)
    {
        *this = rhs;
    }
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    point3d& operator=(const point3d& rhs)
    {
        x = rhs.x;
        y = rhs.y;
        z = rhs.z;
        return *this;
    }
    point3d operator-(const point3d& rhs) const
    {
        return point3d(x - rhs.x, y - rhs.y, z - rhs.z);
    }
    double square_norm() const
    {
        return x*x + y*y + z*z;
    }
};

vector<std::pair<point3d, point3d>> find_point_pairs_by_max_distance(vector<point3d>& points, double max_distance)
{
    vector<std::pair<point3d, point3d>> ret;
    double square_max_distance = max_distance*max_distance;

    std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(),
        [&](const point3d& a, const point3d& b)
    {
        return a.x < b.x;
    });

    for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size();++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = i+1; j < points.size();++j)
        {
            double dx = points[i].x - points[j].x;
            if (dx*dx >= square_max_distance) break;

            double square_distance = (points[i] - points[j]).square_norm();
            if (square_distance < square_max_distance)
            {
                ret.push_back({ points[i], points[j] });
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void print_point(const point3d& point)
{
    cout << '(' << point.x << ',' << point.y << ',' << point.z << ')';
}

void print_point_pairs(const vector<std::pair<point3d, point3d>>& point_pairs)
{
    for (auto& v: point_pairs)
    {
        print_point(v.first);
        cout << ' ';
        print_point(v.second);
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<point3d> points{ point3d(1, 2, 3), point3d(2, 3, 4), point3d(2, 2, 2) };
    auto point_pairs = find_point_pairs_by_max_distance(points,1.5);
    print_point_pairs(point_pairs);
}
```

If your points are bounded in a small region,and Rcut is not very small,you can quantizate the coordinate components by Rcut,then add each point to the corresponding voxel list in a bounded cube,then you only need search for a small Rcut-neighbourhood.This is O(n * (2*Rcut+1)^3)

Comment: Thx. Using a piecewise calculation seems to be my best option here.